# when I add IK, my bone moves out of place in Blender 2.8

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify, inverse-kinematics

please see the picture, after adding IK the bone is moving out of my character, please help.[image]

Comment: That is how it works normally. You need to move Target bone to match tail of selected bone (in edit mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks "Serge L" here I did it.
I want to show the solution with picture so that if anyone else have this problem it help them as well.
When I created my IK bone, I deformed it and also cleared parent but mistakenly moved it away from armature, that was the problem. so as you can see from the picture below, you should extrude a new bone, deform it and clear parent then add ik, but be aware to not move it from its place.
[image]

Comment: this doesn't explain why the arms are moving when the IK just does stuff with the legs, which are parented to an unmoving spine